# How to stop a loop at a certain number/time?

Tags: loops

How do you stop a loop at a certain number, for example, i want to stop the loop at 28th time. So, i programme it to repeat a question for 28th time, and then stop and say Thank you for your kebab orders.

Comment: Please show us what you tried and what you are having a difficulty with.

Comment: Well, by definition a loop goes a certain number of times. In every language you can make it stop at whatever iteration (that's what they are called) number.

Please provide specifics of your problems, at least the language in which you want to do it.

It would be nice a celebratory kebab... yes.

Comment: Well, you need to clarify what do you want to do but I will try to help you by using for loop you’re stopping condition exist in for (int i=0;i<28;i ++) this loop will be terminated after 28 times

Answer (score 0):

You would do a for loop

```
for (int I = 1; I<=28; I++)
{
    //ENTER YOUR CODE
}
```